# Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' By calling UniswapV2Router02 swapExactTokensForETH

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, etherscan

I am trying to call UniswapV2Router02 swapExactTokensForETH function on my Solidity Contract.

I got Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'  on etherscan.
this is transaction url : https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x5970c88d59cacdb33ac68ffe0785b9084309cbc5992d971293d24099af663ab7

than, I debug the transaction using  https://dashboard.tenderly.co/

I found that the real error occur at Dai.sol
Error msg is  "Dai/insufficient-balance"
[image]

Did some one know what's happen?
plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

If there was a shared code, it could be more convenient to say the issue.

but, as you may be aware, before letting the UniswapRouter to do the swap you should "approve" the token like token.approve(_spender, _amount)

Answer (score 0):

Before swapping you need to call 'approve' function an example would be. You need to do this with most ERC20 tokens here is a full example:
This example shows that you need to send aprove tx wait for it and then send buy one.

```
    const BUSDamountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 18);
    let amounts = await routerContract.getAmountsOut(BUSDamountIn, [BUSD, WBNB]);
    const WBNBamountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(10));

    console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(BUSDamountIn));
    console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(WBNBamountOutMin));

    const approveTx = await busdContract.approve(
        router,
        BUSDamountIn
    );
    let reciept = await approveTx.wait();
    console.log(reciept);

    const swapTx = await routerContract.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        BUSDamountIn,
        WBNBamountOutMin,
        [BUSD, WBNB],
        wallet.address,
        Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10,
        {gasLimit: 250000}
    )

    receipt = await swapTx.wait();
    console.log(receipt);
```